# Constructing a block diagonal matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a problem in transforming a matrix into a block diagonal matrix.

My matrix has the form:

Mat= 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & c & 0 \\
 b & 0 & 0 & c \\
 c & 0 & 0 & b \\
 0 & c & b & a \\
\end{array}

I want to construct a block diagonal matrix by using Kronecker product and the other process related to matrices.

BDMat=\begin{array}{cc}
 A & 0 \\
 0 & B \\
\end{array}

where $A$ and $B$ are the 2*2 matrices.

Of course I am looking for a unitary matrix that can create this kind of Block diagonal matrix
like U in

```
U.Mat.Inverse[U]=BDMat
```

Comment: I don't see how the 4x4 matrix in the beginning and the 2 x 2 block matrix afterwards are related. Would you plese elaborate?

Comment: "Of course I am looking for..." You are joking, right?

Comment: in second matrix A and B are 2 x 2 and zero is 2 x 2 zero matrix  too